# OnLoad event not working with Google search on Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm using an onLoad event on a Firefox extension to detect each time a page is loaded and display a Javascript alert (first example on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load).

I realized it doesn't work well with Google search engine (i.e. If you change your keyword and display a new search there isn't a new Javascript alert displayed).

Does someone know how to make the alert appear each you type one or several keyworks and press "Enter" or click on "Search" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to use the event "change" in the event listener !

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can look for the `keyup`/`keydown` event on the search form and filter for Enter (13). And you can watch the `click` event on the search button(s). That should do what you want, although it would mean pretty tight coupling with Google search, so you would have to update your selector/logic every time Google makes a change to their page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm searching for examples of how to do this -being a newbie- (catch the keyup/keydown event and the click on the Google search form) but haven't found so far. Do you know some tutorials ?

Comment: I've noticed that pressing the key Enter redirects to the first website listed on the results of the search so it won't work alone.

Comment: @Bruno Pour un débuttant, je conseille to look and understand how events work, possibly with the help of a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com). You can first build what you want in a (GreaseMonkey) Userscript, for example, which is closer conceptually from a webpage than an extension... and then port it over. Mais c'est ton choix.

Comment: Thanks for your piece of advice ! (and your French words :-)